# I am using my android phone with API 15 as a testing device. I try to run this application and it'stops running on my device just after it's loaded

Tags: java, android, sqlite, runtime-error

It's fairly simple. I am trying to learn how to establish sqlite connection for an android application.
I am using Android Studio to write the code. When I try to load the app on my testing device - Android Phone of API 15 - a white screen flashes and an alert box pops up saying "LearnDB has stopped working".

> Please tell me where I am going wrong.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE- Please try to explain how a sqlite connection should be exactly established and what rules should I definitely keep in mind while doing the same.
>   Feel free to tell me any good programming practices while working with sqlite for android.

This is my MainActivity.java file.

```
    package com.example.summer.learndb;

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private SQLiteDatabase db ;
        public static final String DB_NAME = "scoreDb.db";
        public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT         EXISTS scoreTable (score1 INTEGER, score2 INTEGER);";
        public static final String DB_TABLE = "scoreTable";
        Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,         SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
            db.close();
            try{
                db.execSQL(DB_TABLE);
                db.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Table created!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ERROR!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                }
            });
            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){

                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is my activity_main.xml file.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="show"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well post the logcat. There you will find whats the problem.

Comment: one thing what is wrong, You call db.close(); after creating the database and  then You want to execute a sql...next thing is, You gave Your buttons the id button1, that´s not a good idea. Be aware that You use the correct import of R. , button1 is internal id for button and if You imported the wrong R. (android.R.) then You refer a wrong layout...But anyway, post the logcat, otherwise nobody knows the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take one context and write following code.

   ```
   public Context context;
   db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("scoreDb.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   ```
2. You need to remove following line that you have written exactly after openorCreateDatabase().

   ```
   db.close();
   ```
3. Write this

   ```
   db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   db.execSQL(DB_TABLE);
   ```

Comment: correct, but I think the exception is thrown because of another mistake. the execSQL is inside a try/catch, so it will be catched and this could not be the cause of the crash..

Answer (score 1):

Ram Mansawala is absolutely wright, but I think You have another problem. Your db.execSQL is inside a try catch, so it will not be the cause of the crash. What You have done is, to initialize buttons before setContentView. That´s a problem, because the system cannot find them. Do it like this:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db ;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "scoreDb.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT         EXISTS scoreTable (score1 INTEGER, score2 INTEGER);";
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "scoreTable";
    Button b1;
    Button b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,         SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);

               . 
               .
               .
             etc
```

Initialize Your buttons **after** setContentView()

### EDIT

Explaining how sqlite should be implemented is out of range here, but here are good tutorials:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/sqlite/sqlitedatabase/android-sqlite-example/

Comment: yes, i agree. Its must be written after setContentView().